# does Bootstrap add classes depending on what device it is?

Tags: css, class, twitter-bootstrap, tablet

i.e. if you're on a tablet is there a class added to body called 'tablet' or something similar..?

Bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: No. Everything is styled using media queries with targeting specific screen widths.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to do that yourself.

However, Bootstrap uses Media Queries and some Helper Classes to style the content for different devices (depending on the screen size)

Comment: yeh i know that - its just that several other frameworks I used did add a class describing the device type. I used it a lot to show elements on touch screens that were shown on hover via trackpads & mice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want these features:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities
If you are using the last version (3.1.1)

You'll be able to custom the interface depending on the current size of the screen using CSS classes.

*Edit*:

On older versions such as 2.3.2 it's here:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive

The new version is more powerful with more choices but the old one is easier to understand. (`visible-tablet`, etc.)